# Crash in GoogleMaps iOS sdk gmscore::renderer::GLEntity::Draw

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am using GoogleMaps to show markers on specific longitude and latitude. But I am getting the following crash on crashlytics.

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libGLProgrammability.dylib     0x377d0 glvmRasterOpDepthStencilTest
1  libGLProgrammability.dylib     0x86195 glvmInterpretFPTransformFour
2  GLRendererFloat                0x12986 gldLLVMFPTransform2x2
3  GLRendererFloat                0x11af8 gldMergeScanlines2x2
4  GLRendererFloat                0x27feb gldLLVMVecPolyRender
5  GLRendererFloat                0xf540 gldRenderFillPolygonPtr
6  GLEngine                       0xded21 gleLLVMVecPrimMultiRender
7  GLEngine                       0x1e6f7 gleFlushAtomicFunc
8  GLEngine                       0x6b10d glDrawElements_IMM_ES2Exec
9  MyProjectName                     0xcd4d7d gmscore::renderer::GLEntity::Draw(gmscore::renderer::EntityRenderer*, gmscore::renderer::RenderBin*, GMSPassID) + 827
10 MyProjectName                     0xcd9656 void gmscore::renderer::RenderBin::PerformDraw<std::__1::__tree_const_iterator<gmscore::base::reffed_ptr<gmscore::renderer::BaseEntity>, std::__1::__tree_node<gmscore::base::reffed_ptr<gmscore::renderer::BaseEntity>, void*>*, long> >(std::__1::__tree_const_iterator<gmscore::base::reffed_ptr<gmscore::renderer::BaseEntity>, std::__1::__tree_node<gmscore::base::reffed_ptr<gmscore::renderer::BaseEntity>, void*>*, long>, std::__1::__tree_const_iterator<gmscore::base::reffed_ptr<gmscore::renderer::BaseEntity>, std::__1::__tree_node<gmscore::base::reffed_ptr<gmscore::renderer::BaseEntity>, void*>*, long>, gmscore::renderer::EntityRenderer*, bool) + 134
11 MyProjectName                     0xda2a0d gmscore::vector::GMSVectorTileRenderBin::Draw(gmscore::renderer::EntityRenderer*) + 87
12 MyProjectName                     0xcd25ae gmscore::renderer::EntityRenderer::Draw(bool) + 980
13 MyProjectName                     0xd6c1d5 -[GMSPhoenixRenderer drawForced:] + 62
14 MyProjectName                     0xd4e6b0 -[GMSEntityRendererView draw] + 399
15 MyProjectName                     0xd9dadf -[GMSVectorMapView draw] + 42
16 MyProjectName                     0xd4cc1c -[GMSEntityRendererView displayLinkFired:] + 46
17 MyProjectName                     0xd4b796 -[GMSDisplayLink displayLinkFired:] + 394
18 QuartzCore                     0xf474 CA::Display::DisplayLink::dispatch_items(unsigned long long, unsigned long long, unsigned long long) + 932
19 QuartzCore                     0x10e9c6 display_timer_callback(__CFMachPort*, void*, long, void*) + 395
20 CoreFoundation                 0x4eb42 __CFMachPortPerform + 157
21 CoreFoundation                 0x83125 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 41
22 CoreFoundation                 0x824cc __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 617
23 CoreFoundation                 0x7c901 __CFRunLoopRun + 2420
24 CoreFoundation                 0x7ba90 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 562
25 GraphicsServices               0x3c8e GSEventRunModal + 139
26 UIKitCore                      0xcda90e -[UIApplication _run] + 928
27 UIKitCore                      0xcdf569 UIApplicationMain + 101
28 MyProjectName                     0x7cf09f main + 12 (AppDelegate.swift:12)
29 ???                            0x110b23f21 (Missing)
30 ???                            0x20879351e (Missing)
31 ???                            0x20878e000 (Missing)
```

I have read [this](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/224584852) thread but found no solution. I thought it might have been fixed in pod version 6.2.1 but I have tried `pod 'GoogleMaps', '6.2.1'` still no solution. My crash is happening in the following environment:

```
Xcode 13.3.1
simulator iPhone 13
iOS 15.4
```

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?